# Passing data from one scene to another isn't working? (doing it the same way i have for all others)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Basically I am trying to enter 2 dates that will pass through to 2 different strings in another controller, so that it changes the text in the Bar Graph so it runs the report.

The code when selecting the 2 dates:

```
 public void okayBtnPressed() throws SQLException, IOException{
        con = handler.getConnection();

        int count = 0;

        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM assigned WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        pst.setString(1, datePickerFrom.getValue().toString());
        pst.setString(2, datePickerTo.getValue().toString());
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/bownhrmain1/reports/assignedReport.fxml"));
        Parent root = myLoader.load();
        AssignedReportController assignedController = myLoader.getController();

        while(rs.next()){
            count ++;
        }

        if(count == 0){
          // no results  
        } else {        
            System.out.println(""+count);
            System.out.println(datePickerFrom.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println(datePickerTo.getValue().toString());

            date1 = datePickerFrom.getEditor().getText();
            date2 = datePickerTo.getEditor().getText();

            assignedController.date1 = date1;
            assignedController.date2 = date2;
            assignedController.amount = count;

            Stage window = (Stage)(okayBtn.getScene()).getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            window.setScene(scene);           
        }     
    }
```

All the system.out lines print the correct date, in this case it prints the correct dates and it returns a row value on 1.

This report is displaying the number of items that have been assigned out to employees between 2 different dates.

This is the code to apply the data to a bar graph: (This is the assignedController)

```
 public String date1 = "";
    public String date2 = "";
    public String totalDate = "";
    public int amount;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        totalDate = date1+" - "+date2;        
        System.out.println(totalDate);
        System.out.println(""+amount);

        XYChart.Series set1 = new XYChart.Series<>();

        set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(totalDate, amount));

        barChart1.getData().addAll(set1);
    }
```

I get no errors, but the amount int in assignedController is = 0 and both strings return nothing.

This is the fxml for the bar graph page:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="737.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="reports.AssignedReportController">
   <children>
      <BarChart fx:id="barChart1" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="44.0" title="Stock Assigned">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis fx:id="monthAxis" label="Month" side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis fx:id="amountAxis" label="Amount Sold" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </BarChart>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initialize()` method in a controller is called during the execution of `FXMLLoader.load()`, which of course is before you set the values in the controller. You need to call a method on the controller that updates the data. (This is a good example of why you should never use public fields - it allows for those fields to be changed without controlling what happens to other fields (the bar chart, in this case) that may depend on them.)

You need something like

```
public class AssignedReportController {

    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barchart1 ;


    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> set1 ;

    public void initialize() {
        set1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        barChart1.getData().add(set1);
    }

    public void setDates(String date1, String date2, int amount) {
        String totalDate = date1 + " - " + date2 ;
        set1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(totalDate, amount));
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then in your button handler you just need

```
date1 = datePickerFrom.getEditor().getText();
date2 = datePickerTo.getEditor().getText();
assignedController.setDates(date1, date2, count);
```

As an aside, you should consider using a count function in your SQL for this, and you should close JDBC resources that you are no longer using:

```
public void okayBtnPressed() throws SQLException, IOException{
    con = handler.getConnection();

    String query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assigned WHERE Date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
    pst.setString(1, datePickerFrom.getValue().toString());
    pst.setString(2, datePickerTo.getValue().toString());
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    int count = rs.next().getInt(1);

    rs.close();
    pst.close();

    FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/bownhrmain1/reports/assignedReport.fxml"));
    Parent root = myLoader.load();
    AssignedReportController assignedController = myLoader.getController();

    if(count == 0){
      // no results  
    } else {        
        System.out.println(""+count);
        System.out.println(datePickerFrom.getValue().toString());
        System.out.println(datePickerTo.getValue().toString());

        date1 = datePickerFrom.getEditor().getText();
        date2 = datePickerTo.getEditor().getText();

        assignedController.setDates(date1, date2, count);

        Stage window = (Stage)(okayBtn.getScene()).getWindow();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);           
    }     
}
```